# Как соотносятся JAVA EE и JVM?

Tags: java, java-ee

Общеизвестно, что Java EE - это набор спецификаций. GlassFish - это одна из реализаций этой спецификации (есть и другие реализации, например Tomcat, итд).
Java SE - это грубо говоря JVM + стандартные библиотеки + средства компиляции (разработки)

Собственно, теперь вопрос. Объясните, пожалуйста, при установке GlassFish или Tomcat, эти серверы приложений используют под собой JVM (от JAVA SE) и стандартные (базовые) библиотеки или при установке сервера приложений ставится свой JVM?
Означает ли это что при установке какой-нибудь реализации JAVA EE устанавливается также JAVA SE, так как первому нужно юзать JVM и стандартные (базовые) библиотеки?

Comment: Почитайте спецификацию каждой EE, там есть описание и установка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте определимся с терминологией:

1. JVM это среда в которой выполняется Java приложение. Бывают разные JVM - навскидку их несколько десятков (под сотню я думаю). Православная JVM от Oracle/Sun имеет 2 версии клиентскую и серверную.
2. Java SE набор стандартных библиотек от Sun/Oracle
3. Java EE - набор спецификаций, которые может реализовать более-менее любой вендор, используя в том числе Java SE. Имеется т.н. референсная реализация Java EE от Sun/Oracle.

Соответственно реализация Java EE обычно работает под серверной JVM используя библиотеки Java SE + еще какие-то другие (специфичные для вендора).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Получается после установки одной из реализаций Java EE (например Tomcat) помимо специфичных для Java EE библиотек, как правило, устанавливается серверный JVM, также устанавливается Java SE (так как по вашим словам это набор стандартных библиотек)?

Comment: Если речь идет о рантайме, то Java SE не нужен, все либы уже должны быть упакованы в JAR/WAR/EAR исполняемого модуля, а JVM (он же JRE) конечно должен быть

Comment: Не... я про то, что действительно ли после установки реализации JAVA EE (Tomcat),  сразу устанавливаются реализация библиотек спецификации JAVA EE, а также реализация библиотек спецификации JAVA SE?

Comment: я просто думал, что реализация библиотек по спецификации  JAVA SE, это отдельная сгруппированная единица, которая устанавливается на машину. И когда мы устанавливаем одну из реализаций JAVA EE, устанавливается некая "группа" библиотек JAVA SE отдельно. А вы вроде поправили меня, что реализация JAVA EE это есть набор пакетов из JAVA EE и JAVA SE